# How to convert JSON to list of key with dotnotation

Tags: javascript

I am converting JSON keys to the list with dot-notation. If any dot is there represent nested jsonobject and if any [](array notation) is there resents jsonarray.

```
var keyify = (obj, prefix = '') =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, el) => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[el])) {
      return [...res, ...keyify(obj[el][0], prefix + el + '[].')];
    } else if (typeof obj[el] === 'object' && obj[el] !== null) {
      return [...res, ...keyify(obj[el], prefix + el + '.')];
    } else {
      return [...res, prefix + el];
    }
  }, []);
```

Above is the sample code that I am using for the converion. If input is

```
{
  "input": {
    "test": {
      "phone": [
        {
          "phone1": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customer": [
    {
      "lastname": "def",
      "firstname": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output will be:

```
[ 'input.test.phone[].phone1',
  'customer[].lastname',
  'customer[].firstname' ]
```

But the above code searches for only first JSONObject's keys in the JSONArray. But if the input is like this:

```
{
  "input": {
    "test": {
      "phone": [
        {
          "phone1": "123"
        },
        {
          "a": "456"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customer": [
    {
      "lastname": "def",
      "firstname": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in the above JSON case the code will give output :

```
[ 'input.test.phone[].phone1',
  'customer[].lastname',
  'customer[].firstname' ]
```

So, the key `a` is missing only `phone1` is coming in the list.So, how to get if multiple json keys are there then get keys with index of first occurence.
Expected output

```
[ 'input.test.phone[0].phone1',
  'input.test.phone[1].a',
  'customer[0].lastname',
  'customer[0].firstname' ]
```

And if the JSONarray is value then it should be replaced by empty string.

For input:

```
const data = {
  "input": {
    "test": {
      "phone": [
        {
          "phone1": ["123456"]
        },
        {
          "a": ["1","2","3","4"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customer": [
    {
      "lastname": "def",
      "firstname": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case `"phone1": ["123456"]` and `"a": ["1","2","3","4"]` are Json array as values this case lis will be like:
Expected Output:

```
[ 'input.test.phone[0].phone1',//instead of 'input.test.phone[0].phone1[0]'
  'input.test.phone[1].a',//instead of 'input.test.phone[1].a[0]','input.test.phone[1].a[1]','input.test.phone[1].a[2]','input.test.phone[1].a[3]',
  'customer[0].lastname',
  'customer[0].firstname' ]
```

In the above case jsonarray should be considered as value not key.

Comment: There are no such things as "JSONObject" or "JSONArray"

Comment: Maybe a library like [dot-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object) or [flatten-obj](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatten-obj) could help you? They're not exactly doing what you want, but they may help, or other similar packages may do it directly

Comment: @Andreas There is a JSONObject and JSONArray in the `net.sf.json` Java library. I think that this is what OP meant.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl This might be the case but this is about JavaScript and there are no such things. Using the right names makes it easier to find answers for a problem, hence...

Comment: @Andreas I agree, but if they starting with Java and have moved into the realm of JavaScript, this may be their understanding of the object types.

Comment: @JeremyThille is there any java library likewhat you have shared becuse it is exaclty what I wanted

Comment: Java? Why Java? I have no idea, I never wrote a line of Java in my life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `for...in` loop to create recursive function for this and check if the current data input is an array or not to add dot or square brackets.

```js
const data =  { "input": { "test": { "phone": [ { "phone1": ["123456"] }, { "a": ["1","2","3","4"] } ] } }, "customer": [ { "lastname": "def", "firstname": "abc" } ] }

function parse(data, prev = '') {
  const result = []

  const check = data => {
    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
      return false
    }

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      if (data.some(e => (typeof e != 'object'))) {
        return false
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  for (let i in data) {
    let dot = prev ? '.' : ''
    let str = Array.isArray(data) ? `[${i}]` : dot + i
    let key = prev + str;


    if (check(data[i])) {
      result.push(...parse(data[i], key))
    } else {
      result.push(key)
    }
  }

  return result
}

const result = parse(data);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, one more help I have updated the code for the input:::: {
  "input": {
    "test": {
      "phone": [
        {
          "phone1": ["123456"]
        },
        {
          "a": ["1","2","3","4"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customer": [
    {
      "lastname": "def",
      "firstname": "abc"
    }
  ]
}       , if jsonarray is not having jsonobject it should treat it as value.Please see the updated question.

Comment: I have asked similar question for getting xpath, please can you have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948920/convertion-of-json-to-json-key-list-with-dotnotation?noredirect=1#comment107830195_60948920

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested approach by having a look to the types of the object.

```js
function flat(object, keys = '') {
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return [keys];

    if (Array.isArray(object))
        return object.every(o => !o|| typeof o!== 'object')
            ? [keys]
            : object.flatMap((o, i, { length }) =>
                flat(o, `${keys}[${length === 1 ? '' : i}]`));

    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => flat(v, `${keys}${keys && '.'}${k}`));
}

var data = { input: { test: { phone: [{ phone1: ["123456"] }, { a: ["1", "2", "3", "4"] }] } }, customer: [{ lastname: "def", firstname: "abc" }] },
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated the question.Incase of jsonarray without any jsonobject it should be treated as value.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse through the scope of the object and capture any paths that have a non-object value.

This is an extremely uncoupled and generic soulution.

```js
const traverse = (obj, visitorFn, scope = []) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    visitorFn.apply(this, [key, obj[key], scope]);
    if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      traverse(obj[key], visitorFn, scope.concat(key));
    }
  }
}

const scopeToPath = (obj) => obj.reduce((path, key) =>
  path + (!isNaN(key) ? `[${key}]` : `.${key}`), '').substring(1);

const findObjectPaths = (obj) => {
  let paths = [];
  traverse(obj, (key, value, scope) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'object') {
      paths.push(scopeToPath(scope.concat(key)));
    }
  });
  return paths;
};

console.log(findObjectPaths(getData()));

function getData() {
  return {
    "input": {
      "test": {
        "phone": [{ "phone1": "123" }, { "a": "456" }]
      }
    },
    "customer": [{ "lastname": "def", "firstname": "abc" }]
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated the question.Incase of jsonarray without any jsonobject it should be treated as value.